# Objective-C NSArray objects to UiLabel setText(which is in loop)

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, nsstring, nsarray, uilabel

I have a UIScrollView with enabled paging.
For every page in Scroll i want to change the text in UILabel.
Eg. 30 NSArray objects=30 pages.

I got it working without NSArray, but i really need to load NSArray object(s) to the page.

`//view did load...All that scroll view properties and other crap`

```
CGRect pageFrame ;
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"A", @"B", @"C", nil];

for (int i = 0 ; i < kNumberOfPages ; i++)
{


    pageFrame = CGRectMake(i * scrollView.bounds.size.width, 0.0f, scrollView.bounds.size.width, scrollView.bounds.size.height) ;


    labelOne = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: pageFrame] ;

    [scrollView addSubview: labelOne] ;
    [labelOne release] ;


    [labelOne setFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 140.0f]] ;
    [labelOne setTextAlignment: UITextAlignmentCenter] ;
    [labelOne setTextColor: [UIColor darkTextColor]] ;
    [labelOne setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    for (NSString *new in arr){
        [labelOne setText:new];
        NSLog(new);

    }
}
[scrollView release];
```

And it throws an exception.
Any ideas?
Basically, i need to get every object from my array to setText(NSString).

Thanks!

Comment: Where does it throw an exception?

Comment: @middaparka
[scrollView release]; <-Thread 1:Stopped at breakpoint


Really, really don't know why.:/  
All the { and } seem alright, it builds fine without errors.

Comment: Why are you attempting to release the UIScrollView there? (Where it is being alloced/inited?)

Comment: Well, since the ScrollView is the second controller.


And i am using IBAction and UIButton to open it.

And this is the code:
<code>- (IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender {
 SecondViewController *newview = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
 [self.view addSubview:newview.view];
} 
</code>

Now it throws exception at:
 [self.view addSubview:newview.view];
Saying: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: We need more code, but that release there is almost certainly a bug.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem.  Also, there was a problem in my IBAction which probably caused the leak. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Still, take that code up there(minus that release) and you should get the proper code.  Except, it only prints the last object from array(in setText). But, in LOG it dumps the objects like it should.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** (because I misread the question originally...):

Two problems.  As @Eiko says, you need to remove the `[scrollView release];` line.

Then, the problem is that you keep looping through your array and replacing the text with the next string, which will end up only setting the label text to your last string.  You need to use just the one string in the corresponding position in the array.

Instead of:

```
for (NSString *new in arr){
    [labelOne setText:new];
    NSLog(new);

}
```

Use this:

```
[labelOne setText:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];
```